# Phase transition and effect on leptogenesis

Tags: standard-model, phase-transition, electroweak, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

What is the effect on leptogenesis in the standard model if the electroweak phase transition is (i) first order and (ii) second order?

Answer (score 1):

In the Standard Model there is neither first nor second order electroweak phase transition (EWPT), but rather a crossover. To get a first order transition, additional particles are needed. There are many different theories ([2HDM](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+2HDM/0/1/0/all/0/1), [Higgs portal](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+AND+higgs+portal/0/1/0/all/0/1), [MSSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Supersymmetric_Standard_Model), ...) covering this topic.

Considering leptogenesis $\Delta L \neq 0$ we need a first order PT, since non-equilibrium is one of the [Sakharov conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#Sakharov_conditions) required for leptogenesis. If these conditions are fulfilled, [sphaleron processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphaleron) violate lepton (or baryon) number by "jumping" from the symmetric $(\phi = 0)$ to the broken $(\phi=\phi_0)$ phase. I found this plot: (Never mind the numbers, in the case of EWPT the critical temperature $T_c \sim \mathcal{O}(100 GeV)$ )

[image]

Comment: This looks like a first order transition to me, or am I misreading the plot?